# How do I share a folder between two ubuntu 14.04 machine and access it using terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, share

I am using two ubuntu 14.04 machine on same network, say A and B. I have a folder in A which i need to share with B. I connected A with B using 'Connect to Server' option. Post which i was able to access all files and folders present on machine A. But am not able to access the same through terminal.

Please suggest a way to achieve accessing of remote folder using terminal between two Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried scp?
say you have two machines A and B then you'd open your terminal and do

```
scp user@A:/path/to/folder/on/A user@B:/destination/path/on/b
```

see here for a generic example https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal on machine B and type:

```
sudo sftp machine_A_username@ip_of_machine_A
```

Inside sftp, you can use `put` & `get` for files transfer.

You can also mount a folders via /etc/[fstab](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=what%20is%20fstab&oq=what%20is%20fstab&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2355j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=fstab).